# Link to a network location using file:// does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, hudson, jenkins

Our daily builds are stored in a shared network directory. My team wants me to put a link to that location on the results page - the most natural place would be among the artifacts. Clicking on that link should open the folder for viewing, copying, etc.

I've tried to implement the following solution: create an html file that redirects to the network directory and save it as an artifact. Here's the html file I generate (let's call it `LinkToInstallation.html`):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.location='file:////file_server/dir_path'
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Jenkins puts a link to this file among the artifacts. When I click on it from IE it redirects just fine, but from Chrome no redirection occurs, just an empty page is displayed. If I download the file (via `Save Link As`) and open it locally with Chrome - it works.

(1) Is there a workaround so that people do not have to change their Chrome settings?
(2) If not, how should Chrome be set up to redirect properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome does not permit web pages to link to `file://` URLs unless they were themselves loaded from `file://` URLs. This is as a security precaution, as web pages running from `file://` have permissions to read any file on your system. Similar restrictions apply for most other browsers.

Any reason you can't run an internal web server from your shared network directory? That'd solve the problem neatly.

Comment: >Any reason you can't run an internal web server from your shared network directory?

Please elaborate. Thanks!!

Comment: Another try: @duskwuff, I'm not sure what you mean that I should try to run my web server from a shared network directory. The web server I am talking about is an "internal" one run by Jenkins. On the machine on which it runs the network directory is available (under the same name as for everybody). Thanks.

Comment: Run another web server, using Apache or IIS or whatever is most convenient. Point it to the network directory. Link to files as served by it over HTTP, instead of `file://`.